# Inline quote possible

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Is there a way to do a quote:

> like so

inline similar to `code block`?

While attempting, > This doesn't work > or > this <

I want to bring attention to my inline quote, and I don't feel quotations marks are enough.

Comment: An inline quote generally uses..."quotation marks".

Comment: You could even use quotation marks within a `"code block"`.

Comment: @hims056 Erm, you're wrong.

Comment: @hims056 **No**. Code blocks are for inline code. They have semantic and visual meaning. Do *not* use them for inline quotations.

Comment: There's the `<q>` tag <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q>, though it doesn't actually work in StackExchange…

Answer (score 15):

Yes, quotation marks. That's what they do.

If you want to quote something so short that it should be inline you probably just want to wrap it in quotation marks. Otherwise, if you're actually quoting something substantial, it should be a block-level element.

[Wikipedia tells us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) that "in English writing, quotation marks ... are punctuation marks surrounding a quotation, direct speech, or a literal title or name", which sounds very much like what you're looking for.

As far as something more visually distinct, frankly, we need less bolding/italicizing/inline styles. There is absolutely no reason to mark some parts of your post more important than others. You should be stripping *out* the unimportant parts until only the important parts remain. Whatever quote you're inserting shouldn't require any special visual styles to stand out; if your question is written properly and of a reasonable length, people will read the quote in the course of reading your question.

If you're worried about your quote getting lost, you're filling your question with too much fluff. You should pare it down until there is literally nothing left for you to remove without changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: IMO, we aren't really formatting with english rules. Nothing in english suggests that a quote block have a gray background. I wanted to bring attention to the quote because it's a SO rule, but I can't do that without a code block, which leaves the fixed-width font in place. This isn't a really big concern obviously, but it would be nice to have a way to hightlight inline quotes without using fixed-width font.

Comment: @Xaade In the original post, Xaade said *"I want to bring attention to my inline quote, and I don't feel quotations marks are enough."*. This makes a quote stand out more obviously. Is that sufficient for you? (Can be achieved using `*"..."*` or `_"..."_`)

Comment: I supposed counter-suggestion is going to flood this one out. @RobW I guess that will do.

Comment: See edits. Absolutely disagree with adding additional magic styles for inline quotes. Note @RobW that he *didn't* say that in the original post. He edited it in, in response to my answer.